# Unable to connect to mysql remotely

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database running on a VPS. I can ssh into the host and connect to mysql with no problems. I cannot connect to mysql remotely from my desktop. I have performed the following:

- opened port 3306 on the firewall
- added my local IP to the remote IPs accepted by mysql. This was done via CPanel
- executed

  ```
  GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO username@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'
  ```

to tell mysql to let me connect from the specified address.

I execute the following from the command line on my desktop:

```
mysql -h x.x.x.x -u username -p
```

I get a password prompt which indicates I am past the firewall and mysql is responding. When I supply the password, it denies access:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)

Have I missed something?

Comment: `I get a password prompt which indicates I am past the firewall and mysql is responding.` I think this is where you're wrong. I've seen enough times that `mysql` command line clients would try to connect to a **non-running** `localhost` server and still would prompt a user for credentials...

Comment: Try specifying the database on the command line as the last argument.

Comment: Spot on. I tried with an invalid port number and still got a password prompt. So it is the mysql on my desktop that is prompting me before forwarding to the the remote host. Is there a way of finding out if I am getting past the firewall? Like a ping or a tickle to the mysqld?

Comment: That said, the error message seems to be coming from mysql. When I use an invalid port number I get `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x'` whereas if I use the correct port number I get `Access denied for user 'zzz'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)`. Whatever is answering knows what mysql user is trying to connect and knows I am using a password.

Comment: I've found nmap to be useful for scanning for open ports. nmap x.x.x.x

Comment: `Try specifying the database on the command line as the last argument.` This returns the same error.

Comment: nmap returns a list including `3306/tcp open  mysql`

Comment: From my past experience the password might be wrong. Try explicitly setting up access for the same user for localhost and see if you can connect.

Comment: Personally ... I'd use a ssh tunnel. I never expose mysql databases to public access.

Comment: `From my past experience the password might be wrong.` The password is correct. The user has already been set up for localhost. In fact I copy and paste the command line from the ssh session in the remote host and just change the -h parameter. I am very wary of mis-typed passwords and tend to copy/paste in situations like this.

Comment: Can you check what the result is when you run `select Host,User,Password from mysql.user where User="username";` Verify that there is indeed password for the `username@x.x.x.x`.

Comment: It's quite possible you forgot to run `create user 'username'@'x.x.x.x' identified by 'password';`.

Comment: Have you edit httpd file for remote access?

Comment: @alvits thanks for this. I had done these things, but there was a cockup somewhere in the user table. I deleted all remote users including loads that had been created by CPanel or migrated from another host. I then started from scratch doing create user and grant all and it works now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in the comments, so I will repeat it here to properly close the thread. alvits suspected that the remote user had not been created. It had been created but his comment prompted me to clean up the user table.

I deleted all remote users including loads that had been created by CPanel or migrated from another host. I then started from scratch doing `create user` and `grant all` and it works now.

Thanks!